# Finding the text "space" value in pixels

Tags: c#, c++, text, typography

With dealing with fonts, is there a way to figure out what the space between two characters should be if it was "1 2"?

If it is known in C++ or C#, I don't mind. If it is in C++, I will marshal it over, it if is in C#, I will save it to a file and load it in C++. I tried taking a look at the TextMetric structure but it was not there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, are you asking how to calculate how many pixels a space takes up based on the font it is printed in?

Comment: Are you referring to the graphical distance between characters, or the blank character called space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want metrics of how text will be rendered you need to provide the text. You would need to provide the ascii space character. Modern systems using Kerning to adjust spacing and make text look more attractive.

Answer (score 2):

[Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges.aspx) gets pretty good results measuring single glyphs (even spaces) by adding a zero-width-joiner character `\u200D` before and after. It does however ignore all Kerning stuff, due to the zero-width-joiners I think.

You need a bunch of additional parameters, but a `new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic)` and `Rectangle.Empty` did just fine for me.

It returns an array of nice floating point bounds of each character in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [Graphics.MeasureString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) and pass in a font and `" "` string with space ?

Comment: This method is highly inaccurate for single characters and i think it returns zero for a single space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in C# using a form's Paint event handler:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    float widthWithSpace = e.Graphics.MeasureString("1 2", new Font("Arial", 12)).Width;
    float widthWithoutSpace = e.Graphics.MeasureString("12", new Font("Arial", 12)).Width;
    float spaceWidthInPixels = widthWithSpace - widthWithoutSpace ;
}
```